# Searching a tab/space delimited text file based upon form criteria and returning a 'record' into a word press results page

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query

This is my first foray into turning a current perl (.pl) script into a bit of code within WordPress. We're looking to migrate this process/page which resides on an old web server into WordPress. Please be gentle. :)

Currently, a user completes an HTML form providing search criteria and upon submitting the form, it's posted to a .pl page. A tab(or space)delimited text file (.dat) is read into that .pl page/script. The script sets up arrays to hold the columns/fields from the file. Based upon criteria passed to the .pl file from an html form (name, date, record number, etc.) a sub runs in the .pl file and when a successful match for a record is found, it then formats those returned fields which have been placed into variables as HTML, creating a table row to hold the retrieved data.

I'm unsure if there's a plugin to accomplish this or whether a function call in PHP would be the route to take.

I appreciate any assistance to get me moving in the right direction. I can provide whatever information/specifics if necessary.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary that the data remains in file? Seems to me you might as well port it into a custom SQL table and reap the performance benefits

Comment: Unable to do so. The IT team has the website in a stand alone Azure environment, sadly. But thank you!

Comment: It sort of depends on how you'd like to display this form/table. It could be implemented as a shortcode or a custom Block Editor block if you'd like to be able to place it within post/page content. Or if your company is using a custom theme you might build it as a template